Why do we have fewer distinct Gauss sums over a field of characteristic $2$?
Let $p$ be a prime number and $q$ be a power of $p$. Fix a non-trivial additive character $\psi\colon \mathbb{F}_q\to \mathbb{C}^\times$ and, for each non-trivial multiplicative character $\chi\colon \mathbb{F}_q^\times\to \mathbb{C}^\times$, consider the Gauss sum
$$g(\psi,\chi)= \sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_q^\times}\psi(x)\chi(x).$$
Denote by $S_q$ the set of the $g(\psi,\chi)$ for all non-trivial multiplicative characters $\chi$.
Very often, the set $S_q$ has $q-2$ elements. However, when $q$ is a power of $2$, some numerical experiments seem to imply that the number of elements in $S_q$ is much smaller than $q-2$. For example:



$q$
$q-2$
$|S_q|$




4
2
1


8
6
2


16
14
4


32
30
6


64
62
11



Is it always true that $S_q$ has less than $q-2$ elements when $q$ is a power of $2$? Conversely, is it true that $S_q$ has $q-2$ elements when $q$ is not a power of $2$?
If it's true that $S_q$ always has less than $q-2$ elements when $q$ is a power of $2$, it could be interesting to find a better bound for $|S_q|$ as well.

I have computed slightly farther: the sequence begins 1,2,4,6,11,18,32,58,103,186... It is not in the OEIS, so maybe worthwhile sending it.

continues 342,630,1171,2190.

The number $S_q$ depends on the choice of additive character $\psi$:
changing $\psi$ multiplies each $g(\psi,\chi)$ by some
$(q-1)$-th root of unity depending also on $\chi$;
this is often harmless, but for the present problem it makes a difference.
The usual choice of $\psi$ is $a \mapsto \exp(2 \pi i \, {\rm Tr}(a) / p)$
where $p$ is the characteristic and ${\rm Tr}$ is the trace from
${\bf F}_q$ to ${\bf F}_p = {\bf Z} / p {\bf Z}$;
in our setting $p=2$ so $\psi(a) = (-1)^{{\rm Tr}(a)}$.
This is invariant under Frobenius: $\psi(a) = \psi(a^2)$ for all $a$.
Thus $g(\psi,\chi) = g(\psi,\chi^2) = g(\psi,\chi^4) = \cdots$,
so $S_q$ is at most the number of Frobenius orbits of nontrivial characters,
which is the number of orbits of ${\bf Z} / (q-1) {\bf Z} - \{0\}$
under multiplication by powers of 2.  This accounts for most if not all of
the repeated values of $g(\psi,\chi)$.  The same should happen for
odd $p$ and $q = p^e$ with $e > 1$.
For other choices of $\psi$ one might expect $S_q$ to be equal or near $q-2$.
I checked that $S_8 = 6$ for $\psi$ other than $a \mapsto (-1)^{{\rm Tr}(a)}$.

Dear Noam, You are absolutely right. I tested with other additive characters, and all the others give numbers close to $q-2$ instead of the much smaller numbers given above.
